# PHP forked PDO issue - send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, eloquent

I've just started using a PHP port of Resque (https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/)

It forks PHP threads (how, I'm not so sure...) but because of this I seem to be having issues with the PDO connection.

I use Illuminate\Database which is part of Laravel's package but I use outside of Laravel. This has worked great so far!

It seems with every job I sent to Resque it creates these errors:

```
E_WARNING Error in file 'Connection.php' at line 288: An error occurred in script '/var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php' on line 288: 
Error while sending STMT_PREPARE packet. PID=29799 
E_NOTICE Error in file 'Unknown' at line 0: An error occurred in script 'Unknown' on line 0: 
Unknown: send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
```

From my searching, it says I should try and reconnect to the database, so I added to the setup before the job is ran.

```
DB::connection()->reconnect();
```

And still got similar messages:

```
E_NOTICE Error in file 'Connection.php' at line 826: An error occurred in script '/var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php' on line 826: 
Illuminate\Database\Connection::setPdo(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe 
E_NOTICE Error in file 'Unknown' at line 0: An error occurred in script 'Unknown' on line 0: 
Unknown: send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
```

I'm not sure, how else I can fix this? or is it a MySQL config issue?
I'm running PHP 5.5.21 and MySQL 14.14

Comment: I'd suggest a more complete disconnect/reconnect of that db connection.  Like an `unset` followed by `DB::connection()->reconnect(Config::get('database.default'));`  You want to do that ideally right before using the connection too - not resetting, looping in code for 30 seconds, then using the connection.

Comment: I'm unsure what to unset? How can I access the actual connection variable?